# Unable to execute simple cd command in Python (in Jupyter shell)

Tags: directory

When I attempt to use the following command in Jupyter shell for Python "cd /Users/Donald/Documents/BUS6303/week 7/ocelma-python-recsys-48df9c4/ocelma-python-recsys-48df9c4/recsys/algorithm" I get a Invalid Syntax" error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue when I added a comment in the same cell.  Create a new cell, without a comment, and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify that the folder actually exists?
If so, if could be the space in "week 7".
You could try this:

`cd "/Users/Donald/Documents/BUS6303/week 7/ocelma-python-recsys-48df9c4/ocelma-python-recsys-48df9c4/recsys/algorithm"`